# Powershell Dynamic conditional parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters, conditional-statements

I am writing a script and I want to specify the parameters to do the following:

Parameter 1 is action (either check or kill)
Parameter 2 is computername.

If neither parameter is specified I want my Usage information displayed
Parameter 2 should ONLY be prompted if Parameter 1 is specified.

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
    HelpMessage="Please Enter an Action. (C)heck, (K)ill, or (?) for usage")]
    [String]$Action,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
    Helpmessage="Please Enter One or More Hostnames. seperate multiple hostnames with an , EXAMPLE: Hostname1,Hostname2")]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [String]$Computers 
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why force users to guess at what input is expected?
Just tell them up front what is expected.

For example:

```
Function Test-DescriptiveUserPrompt
{
    [CmdletBinding()]

    Param
    (
        [ValidateSet('C','K')]
        [string]$Action = $(
        Write-Host '
        Please Enter an Action. (C)heck, (K)ill:   ' -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewLine
        Read-Host 
            ),

        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [string[]]$Computers = $(
        Write-Host '
        Please Enter One or More Hostnames. separate multiple hostnames with a comma. 
        EXAMPLE: Hostname1,Hostname2:   ' -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewLine
        Read-Host 
        )
    )

    Process
    {
            "You choose $Action"
            "You enter the list $Computers"
    }
}


# Results

Test-DescriptiveUserPrompt

        Please Enter an Action. (C)heck, (K)ill:   c

        Please Enter One or More Hostnames. seperate multiple hostnames with a comma. 
        EXAMPLE: Hostname1,Hostname2:   localhost,remotehost
c
localhost,remotehost


Test-DescriptiveUserPrompt -Action C -Computers localhost,remotehost

C
localhost
remotehost
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty and simpler way of doing things is to use Parameter Sets. In this case, it will default to displaying the Usage information if things aren't correct.

```
Function Test {
    [CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName = "Action",
    HelpMessage="Please Enter an Action. (C)heck, (K)ill, or (?) for usage")]
    [ValidateSet("C","K","?")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName = "Usage")]
    [String]$Action,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "Action",
    Helpmessage="Please Enter One or More Hostnames. seperate multiple hostnames with an , EXAMPLE: Hostname1,Hostname2")]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [String]$Computers 
    )
Process
{
    if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "Usage" -or $Action -eq "?")
    {
        Write-Host "Usage"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Action"
        Write-Host $Action
        Write-Host $Computers
    }
}
}
```